# How to make an Android ImageView partially transparent

Tags: java, android, transparency, visibility, transparent

I've got some ImageViews in my App and want to make some of them partially transparent, they shouldn't be all gone.
I know the methods setVisibility() and setAlpha(), but the first one is clearly not what I want to do and Eclipse told me that the second one is "deprecated".
So I'd like to know, whether there is a new method, which replaces the setAlpha()-method?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Learn the overloading concept of java. setAlpha(int) and setAlpha(float) is overloaded method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use [`setImageAlpha(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha%28int%29) instead.**

Note that there is also [`setAlpha(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29), which is available for all `View`s and has been introduced in API level 11.

Comment: I saw that method in the small auto-complete window in eclipse, but when i try to use it, it says that this method is not applicable for a parameter of the type double.

Comment: @user2177480 Which method are you talking about? `setImageAlpha` wants an `int`, so you gotta cast it: `setImageAlpha((int) val);`

Comment: I talk about this one: image.setAlpha(i)
I can see that there is one using float and one using int, but when i try e.g. 128.0 it says that it can't handle double-values

Comment: @user2177480 use setImageAlpha(int), otherwise write `128f`.

Comment: Well, it was my first question, so I haven't got the reputation to +1 you ;-)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you want to support all versions of Android, you can add the nineoldandroids package, and use: ViewHelper.setAlpha(imageView, 0.4f);